# Probability that two such randomly generated strings are not identical

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A random bit string of length $n$ is constructed by tossing a fair coin $n$ times and setting a bit to $0$ or $1$ depending on outcomes head and tail, respectively. The probability that two such randomly generated strings are not identical is:

1. $\frac{1}{2^n}$
2. $1 - \frac{1}{n}$
3. $\frac{1}{n!}$
4. $1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$

---

#### My attempt:

So $2$ bit strings will be identical when same sequence of head and tail comes while generating the sequences.

The probability that the two strings are identical is

$(1/2) * (1/2) * ..... * (1/2) (n$ times$)$ which is $=\frac{1}{2^n}$

The probability for not identical is $=1-\frac{1}{2^n}$

---

> Can you please explain in formal way?

Comment: I think your approach is correct.

Comment: Yep there's nothing formal to add - you nailed it.

Comment: your approach is better than the answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. And IMO your reasoning is formal enough.

You find the probability that two strings are the same ($1/2^n$) and so the probability that two strings are different is $1 /2^n$.